# Showing Image Metadata with Less Pipe?

Tags: less, images

I'm watching a [video about less pipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEHxG1OhIFo) and the maker is able to open image files and get back a bunch of meta-data:

[image]

My system seems to have less pipe and I can view PDFs and compressed files with `less`, but I don't get back any meta-data when opening an image. I just get a single line like below.

[image]

I noticed on the video it says `ffmpeg` at the bottom and I do have it installed. Is there some kind of setting I can change to get `less` to show more details for images?

Command used to check less pipe is installed:

```
echo $LESSOPEN
```

Command used to open image:

```
less image.jpg
```

Comment: Could you share the command you used?

Comment: @PauloTomé updated with commands used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [README](https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe) of the `lesspipe` source code code repository, it requires the `identify` utility (from ImageMagick) for jpg, png and gif files.

```
jpg, png, gif requires identify
```

Verifying the `identify` utility I noticed that the ouptup the author of the video from its usage was invoking *with* the `-verbose` flag, whereas the output you obtained (and me in my debian buster system) was *without* the flag:

```
$ identify jpeg-file.jpg
jpeg-file.jpg JPEG 415x415 415x415+0+0 8-bit sRGB 26138B 0.010u 0:00.000
```

```
$ identify -verbose jpeg-file.jpg
Image: jpeg-file.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 415x415+0+0
  Resolution: 96x96
  Print size: 4.32292x4.32292
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 172225
    Red:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 153.031 (0.600122)
      standard deviation: 122.135 (0.478962)
      kurtosis: -1.80175
      skewness: -0.416927
      entropy: 0.323346
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 153.031 (0.600122)
      standard deviation: 122.135 (0.478962)
      kurtosis: -1.80175
      skewness: -0.416927
      entropy: 0.323346
    Blue:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 153.031 (0.600122)
      standard deviation: 122.135 (0.478962)
      kurtosis: -1.80175
      skewness: -0.416927
      entropy: 0.323346
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 153.031 (0.600122)
      standard deviation: 122.135 (0.478962)
      kurtosis: -1.80174
      skewness: -0.41693
      entropy: 0.323346
  Colors: 256
  Histogram:
     54858: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 black
      4225: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 srgb(1,1,1)
      2049: (  2,  2,  2) #020202 srgb(2,2,2)
      1111: (  3,  3,  3) #030303 grey1
       432: (  4,  4,  4) #040404 srgb(4,4,4)
       338: (  5,  5,  5) #050505 grey2
       285: (  6,  6,  6) #060606 srgb(6,6,6)
       349: (  7,  7,  7) #070707 srgb(7,7,7)
       272: (  8,  8,  8) #080808 grey3
       132: (  9,  9,  9) #090909 srgb(9,9,9)
       113: ( 10, 10, 10) #0A0A0A grey4
        86: ( 11, 11, 11) #0B0B0B srgb(11,11,11)
        66: ( 12, 12, 12) #0C0C0C srgb(12,12,12)
       168: ( 13, 13, 13) #0D0D0D grey5
        31: ( 14, 14, 14) #0E0E0E srgb(14,14,14)
        45: ( 15, 15, 15) #0F0F0F grey6
        49: ( 16, 16, 16) #101010 srgb(16,16,16)
        89: ( 17, 17, 17) #111111 srgb(17,17,17)
        28: ( 18, 18, 18) #121212 grey7
        27: ( 19, 19, 19) #131313 srgb(19,19,19)
       290: ( 20, 20, 20) #141414 grey8
        21: ( 21, 21, 21) #151515 srgb(21,21,21)
        24: ( 22, 22, 22) #161616 srgb(22,22,22)
        20: ( 23, 23, 23) #171717 grey9
        20: ( 24, 24, 24) #181818 srgb(24,24,24)
       109: ( 25, 25, 25) #191919 srgb(25,25,25)
        20: ( 26, 26, 26) #1A1A1A grey10
        22: ( 27, 27, 27) #1B1B1B srgb(27,27,27)
        36: ( 28, 28, 28) #1C1C1C grey11
        28: ( 29, 29, 29) #1D1D1D srgb(29,29,29)
        90: ( 30, 30, 30) #1E1E1E srgb(30,30,30)
        29: ( 31, 31, 31) #1F1F1F grey12
        27: ( 32, 32, 32) #202020 srgb(32,32,32)
        20: ( 33, 33, 33) #212121 grey13
        15: ( 34, 34, 34) #222222 srgb(34,34,34)
        17: ( 35, 35, 35) #232323 srgb(35,35,35)
        12: ( 36, 36, 36) #242424 grey14
       227: ( 37, 37, 37) #252525 srgb(37,37,37)
        84: ( 38, 38, 38) #262626 grey15
        18: ( 39, 39, 39) #272727 srgb(39,39,39)
        19: ( 40, 40, 40) #282828 srgb(40,40,40)
        14: ( 41, 41, 41) #292929 grey16
       154: ( 42, 42, 42) #2A2A2A srgb(42,42,42)
        40: ( 43, 43, 43) #2B2B2B grey17
        14: ( 44, 44, 44) #2C2C2C srgb(44,44,44)
        29: ( 45, 45, 45) #2D2D2D srgb(45,45,45)
        10: ( 46, 46, 46) #2E2E2E grey18
         9: ( 47, 47, 47) #2F2F2F srgb(47,47,47)
        14: ( 48, 48, 48) #303030 grey19
       350: ( 49, 49, 49) #313131 srgb(49,49,49)
       217: ( 50, 50, 50) #323232 srgb(50,50,50)
        12: ( 51, 51, 51) #333333 grey20
        11: ( 52, 52, 52) #343434 srgb(52,52,52)
       346: ( 53, 53, 53) #353535 srgb(53,53,53)
        16: ( 54, 54, 54) #363636 grey21
         9: ( 55, 55, 55) #373737 srgb(55,55,55)
        11: ( 56, 56, 56) #383838 grey22
        12: ( 57, 57, 57) #393939 srgb(57,57,57)
         7: ( 58, 58, 58) #3A3A3A srgb(58,58,58)
        10: ( 59, 59, 59) #3B3B3B grey23
         9: ( 60, 60, 60) #3C3C3C srgb(60,60,60)
         5: ( 61, 61, 61) #3D3D3D grey24
        11: ( 62, 62, 62) #3E3E3E srgb(62,62,62)
        12: ( 63, 63, 63) #3F3F3F srgb(63,63,63)
        11: ( 64, 64, 64) #404040 grey25
        16: ( 65, 65, 65) #414141 srgb(65,65,65)
         8: ( 66, 66, 66) #424242 grey26
        19: ( 67, 67, 67) #434343 srgb(67,67,67)
        13: ( 68, 68, 68) #444444 srgb(68,68,68)
       118: ( 69, 69, 69) #454545 grey27
        11: ( 70, 70, 70) #464646 srgb(70,70,70)
        21: ( 71, 71, 71) #474747 grey28
       119: ( 72, 72, 72) #484848 srgb(72,72,72)
        16: ( 73, 73, 73) #494949 srgb(73,73,73)
        11: ( 74, 74, 74) #4A4A4A grey29
        11: ( 75, 75, 75) #4B4B4B srgb(75,75,75)
        14: ( 76, 76, 76) #4C4C4C srgb(76,76,76)
        10: ( 77, 77, 77) #4D4D4D grey30
        12: ( 78, 78, 78) #4E4E4E srgb(78,78,78)
        15: ( 79, 79, 79) #4F4F4F grey31
        10: ( 80, 80, 80) #505050 srgb(80,80,80)
         8: ( 81, 81, 81) #515151 srgb(81,81,81)
         7: ( 82, 82, 82) #525252 grey32
         7: ( 83, 83, 83) #535353 srgb(83,83,83)
        12: ( 84, 84, 84) #545454 grey33
        15: ( 85, 85, 85) #555555 srgb(85,85,85)
         8: ( 86, 86, 86) #565656 srgb(86,86,86)
         7: ( 87, 87, 87) #575757 grey34
        11: ( 88, 88, 88) #585858 srgb(88,88,88)
         9: ( 89, 89, 89) #595959 grey35
         7: ( 90, 90, 90) #5A5A5A srgb(90,90,90)
         6: ( 91, 91, 91) #5B5B5B srgb(91,91,91)
        11: ( 92, 92, 92) #5C5C5C grey36
         8: ( 93, 93, 93) #5D5D5D srgb(93,93,93)
        20: ( 94, 94, 94) #5E5E5E grey37
         7: ( 95, 95, 95) #5F5F5F srgb(95,95,95)
        19: ( 96, 96, 96) #606060 srgb(96,96,96)
        13: ( 97, 97, 97) #616161 grey38
        81: ( 98, 98, 98) #626262 srgb(98,98,98)
        10: ( 99, 99, 99) #636363 grey39
         9: (100,100,100) #646464 srgb(100,100,100)
         6: (101,101,101) #656565 srgb(101,101,101)
         6: (102,102,102) #666666 grey40
         3: (103,103,103) #676767 srgb(103,103,103)
        51: (104,104,104) #686868 srgb(104,104,104)
         7: (105,105,105) #696969 DimGray
        10: (106,106,106) #6A6A6A srgb(106,106,106)
        10: (107,107,107) #6B6B6B grey42
         5: (108,108,108) #6C6C6C srgb(108,108,108)
        11: (109,109,109) #6D6D6D srgb(109,109,109)
         7: (110,110,110) #6E6E6E grey43
         7: (111,111,111) #6F6F6F srgb(111,111,111)
        16: (112,112,112) #707070 grey44
        51: (113,113,113) #717171 srgb(113,113,113)
        14: (114,114,114) #727272 srgb(114,114,114)
         4: (115,115,115) #737373 grey45
        10: (116,116,116) #747474 srgb(116,116,116)
         8: (117,117,117) #757575 grey46
        10: (118,118,118) #767676 srgb(118,118,118)
        35: (119,119,119) #777777 srgb(119,119,119)
        10: (120,120,120) #787878 grey47
         9: (121,121,121) #797979 srgb(121,121,121)
        10: (122,122,122) #7A7A7A grey48
         9: (123,123,123) #7B7B7B srgb(123,123,123)
        10: (124,124,124) #7C7C7C srgb(124,124,124)
         8: (125,125,125) #7D7D7D grey49
         8: (126,126,126) #7E7E7E gray
       176: (127,127,127) #7F7F7F grey50
        12: (128,128,128) #808080 fractal
         9: (129,129,129) #818181 srgb(129,129,129)
        10: (130,130,130) #828282 grey51
        13: (131,131,131) #838383 srgb(131,131,131)
         9: (132,132,132) #848484 srgb(132,132,132)
        16: (133,133,133) #858585 grey52
        73: (134,134,134) #868686 srgb(134,134,134)
       191: (135,135,135) #878787 grey53
        15: (136,136,136) #888888 srgb(136,136,136)
        12: (137,137,137) #898989 srgb(137,137,137)
        16: (138,138,138) #8A8A8A grey54
        17: (139,139,139) #8B8B8B srgb(139,139,139)
        22: (140,140,140) #8C8C8C grey55
         8: (141,141,141) #8D8D8D srgb(141,141,141)
        49: (142,142,142) #8E8E8E srgb(142,142,142)
        21: (143,143,143) #8F8F8F grey56
        10: (144,144,144) #909090 srgb(144,144,144)
         7: (145,145,145) #919191 grey57
         3: (146,146,146) #929292 srgb(146,146,146)
        16: (147,147,147) #939393 srgb(147,147,147)
        36: (148,148,148) #949494 grey58
        15: (149,149,149) #959595 srgb(149,149,149)
         6: (150,150,150) #969696 grey59
        12: (151,151,151) #979797 srgb(151,151,151)
        12: (152,152,152) #989898 srgb(152,152,152)
         7: (153,153,153) #999999 grey60
         6: (154,154,154) #9A9A9A srgb(154,154,154)
         6: (155,155,155) #9B9B9B srgb(155,155,155)
         9: (156,156,156) #9C9C9C grey61
       150: (157,157,157) #9D9D9D srgb(157,157,157)
        11: (158,158,158) #9E9E9E grey62
         4: (159,159,159) #9F9F9F srgb(159,159,159)
         7: (160,160,160) #A0A0A0 srgb(160,160,160)
         7: (161,161,161) #A1A1A1 grey63
         4: (162,162,162) #A2A2A2 srgb(162,162,162)
        12: (163,163,163) #A3A3A3 grey64
        10: (164,164,164) #A4A4A4 srgb(164,164,164)
         9: (165,165,165) #A5A5A5 srgb(165,165,165)
         7: (166,166,166) #A6A6A6 grey65
        11: (167,167,167) #A7A7A7 srgb(167,167,167)
        25: (168,168,168) #A8A8A8 grey66
        14: (169,169,169) #A9A9A9 DarkGray
        17: (170,170,170) #AAAAAA srgb(170,170,170)
        10: (171,171,171) #ABABAB grey67
        44: (172,172,172) #ACACAC srgb(172,172,172)
        12: (173,173,173) #ADADAD grey68
         8: (174,174,174) #AEAEAE srgb(174,174,174)
         9: (175,175,175) #AFAFAF srgb(175,175,175)
         9: (176,176,176) #B0B0B0 grey69
         8: (177,177,177) #B1B1B1 srgb(177,177,177)
         9: (178,178,178) #B2B2B2 srgb(178,178,178)
        14: (179,179,179) #B3B3B3 grey70
        15: (180,180,180) #B4B4B4 srgb(180,180,180)
        15: (181,181,181) #B5B5B5 grey71
         9: (182,182,182) #B6B6B6 srgb(182,182,182)
        10: (183,183,183) #B7B7B7 srgb(183,183,183)
        14: (184,184,184) #B8B8B8 grey72
        11: (185,185,185) #B9B9B9 srgb(185,185,185)
        19: (186,186,186) #BABABA grey73
        56: (187,187,187) #BBBBBB srgb(187,187,187)
       366: (188,188,188) #BCBCBC srgb(188,188,188)
       155: (189,189,189) #BDBDBD grey74
        18: (190,190,190) #BEBEBE grey
        29: (191,191,191) #BFBFBF grey75
       123: (192,192,192) #C0C0C0 silver
        18: (193,193,193) #C1C1C1 srgb(193,193,193)
       148: (194,194,194) #C2C2C2 grey76
        19: (195,195,195) #C3C3C3 srgb(195,195,195)
        10: (196,196,196) #C4C4C4 grey77
         7: (197,197,197) #C5C5C5 srgb(197,197,197)
        16: (198,198,198) #C6C6C6 srgb(198,198,198)
        11: (199,199,199) #C7C7C7 grey78
        17: (200,200,200) #C8C8C8 srgb(200,200,200)
        14: (201,201,201) #C9C9C9 grey79
        35: (202,202,202) #CACACA srgb(202,202,202)
         9: (203,203,203) #CBCBCB srgb(203,203,203)
        12: (204,204,204) #CCCCCC grey80
       153: (205,205,205) #CDCDCD srgb(205,205,205)
        10: (206,206,206) #CECECE srgb(206,206,206)
       107: (207,207,207) #CFCFCF grey81
         9: (208,208,208) #D0D0D0 srgb(208,208,208)
        16: (209,209,209) #D1D1D1 grey82
        17: (210,210,210) #D2D2D2 srgb(210,210,210)
        22: (211,211,211) #D3D3D3 LightGray
        17: (212,212,212) #D4D4D4 grey83
       334: (213,213,213) #D5D5D5 srgb(213,213,213)
        12: (214,214,214) #D6D6D6 grey84
        11: (215,215,215) #D7D7D7 srgb(215,215,215)
        13: (216,216,216) #D8D8D8 srgb(216,216,216)
        63: (217,217,217) #D9D9D9 grey85
        23: (218,218,218) #DADADA srgb(218,218,218)
        17: (219,219,219) #DBDBDB grey86
        19: (220,220,220) #DCDCDC gainsboro
        13: (221,221,221) #DDDDDD srgb(221,221,221)
        14: (222,222,222) #DEDEDE grey87
        30: (223,223,223) #DFDFDF srgb(223,223,223)
       120: (224,224,224) #E0E0E0 grey88
        23: (225,225,225) #E1E1E1 srgb(225,225,225)
        20: (226,226,226) #E2E2E2 srgb(226,226,226)
        16: (227,227,227) #E3E3E3 grey89
        23: (228,228,228) #E4E4E4 srgb(228,228,228)
        18: (229,229,229) #E5E5E5 grey90
        17: (230,230,230) #E6E6E6 srgb(230,230,230)
        16: (231,231,231) #E7E7E7 srgb(231,231,231)
       130: (232,232,232) #E8E8E8 grey91
        19: (233,233,233) #E9E9E9 srgb(233,233,233)
        28: (234,234,234) #EAEAEA srgb(234,234,234)
        33: (235,235,235) #EBEBEB grey92
       230: (236,236,236) #ECECEC srgb(236,236,236)
       252: (237,237,237) #EDEDED grey93
        37: (238,238,238) #EEEEEE srgb(238,238,238)
        53: (239,239,239) #EFEFEF srgb(239,239,239)
        35: (240,240,240) #F0F0F0 grey94
        58: (241,241,241) #F1F1F1 srgb(241,241,241)
        48: (242,242,242) #F2F2F2 grey95
        80: (243,243,243) #F3F3F3 srgb(243,243,243)
       101: (244,244,244) #F4F4F4 srgb(244,244,244)
       124: (245,245,245) #F5F5F5 grey96
       226: (246,246,246) #F6F6F6 srgb(246,246,246)
       170: (247,247,247) #F7F7F7 grey97
       380: (248,248,248) #F8F8F8 srgb(248,248,248)
       307: (249,249,249) #F9F9F9 srgb(249,249,249)
       406: (250,250,250) #FAFAFA grey98
      1012: (251,251,251) #FBFBFB srgb(251,251,251)
      1658: (252,252,252) #FCFCFC grey99
      4279: (253,253,253) #FDFDFD srgb(253,253,253)
     76560: (254,254,254) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
     14197: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 415x415+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 79
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-12-21T23:19:03+00:00
    date:modify: 2019-12-21T23:18:51+00:00
    exif:Artist: Avinash singh
    exif:DateTimeDigitized: 2019:09:30 15:17:42
    exif:DateTimeOriginal: 2019:09:30 15:17:42
    exif:ExifOffset: 2136
    exif:SubSecTimeDigitized: 32
    exif:SubSecTimeOriginal: 32
    exif:WinXP-Author: 65, 0, 118, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 97, 0, 115, 0, 104, 0, 32, 0, 115, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 104, 0, 0, 0
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
    signature: 2b91d43d3440873eaeebf2291d7e1f1f86a169af6cfe5c876ca51c52d7e07e5a
    unknown: 28, 234, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    xmp:CreateDate: 2019-09-30T15:17:42.315
  Profiles:
    Profile-exif: 4338 bytes
    Profile-xmp: 2817 bytes
  Artifacts:
    filename: jpeg-file.jpg
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 26138B
  Number pixels: 172225
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
```

Inspecting the code of the script (that in my system is at `/bin/lesspipe`), at line 133 the `identify` utility is being called *without* the verbose flag.

In conclusion, most probably, the lesspipe script in your system is from a version where identify is called *without* the verbose flag.

The version of [lesspipe.sh](https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe/blob/c3bb06348b9364ad5e0ac177acffb5b054959b04/lesspipe.sh#L954) file in the `lesspipe` source code code repository command `identify` is being called with the flag.